# How to add an item to a list by replacing the earlier one. In Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list will a list but it only has one item I need to be able to replace that with a new one. But there should one be one.
Because there is a condition involve I need to be able to create an variable if something there or not but I found the list to be easier so how can I replace an item in a list with a new one

```
let subject_reply = [];
if (email.subject.startsWith("Re:") == true) {
  subject_reply.push(email.subject);
}else{
  subject_reply.push(`Re: ${email.subject}`);
}
```

Comment: Where is the list ? **Please** add your code so that a proper solution can be provided! Thanks

Comment: Here is the list

Comment: So you have an `array` which has subjects AND you want `replace` the last subject with the new one ?

Comment: `startsWith` returns `true` or `false` anyway - You also do not have to use `== true`

Comment: Maybe you should not be using a list / array if it's only going to hold one value.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps you, to replace an item of an array you can use splice method, this code says: replace item at index 1, delete that item and insert 'Boxer'.

```js
var dogs = ['Bulldog', 'Beagle', 'Labrador'];

dogs.splice(1, 1, 'Boxer'); 

console.log(dogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you asked for, it's an array that holds one item only, by clearing the array when we click on the `button` and it takes the `value` of the `input` and then `push`ing it to the array by making it the only value.

```
If the `value` starts with *Re:*{
 Push as it is.
} else {
 Push: "Re: value"
}
```

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
let subject_reply = [];

myBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  subject_reply = [];
  var textValue = myInput.value;
  if (textValue.startsWith("Re:") == true) {
    subject_reply.push(textValue);
  } else{
    subject_reply.push(`Re: ${textValue}`);
  }
  
  console.log(subject_reply);
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='myInput'>
<button id='myBtn'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Hakuna Matata, sema.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer a poorly-worded question. As I understand it, one of these is the answer you seek:

```
subject_reply.push("Re: " + email.subject.replace(/^Re:\s?/, ""));
```

OR

```
subject_reply[0] = "Re: " + email.subject.replace(/^Re:\s?/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to replace a string value in an array.
For this, Function "Replace()" will help. In this problem specific to you, "EmailREAdder()" will help you adding "RE:" at the start of a string which does not contain "RE:".

```js
/* Function for replacing an item */
const Replace = (arr,oldValue, newValue) => arr.splice(arr.indexOf(oldValue), 1, newValue);

/* Setting all without "RE:"  to RE*/
const EmailREAdder = arr => {
    arr.map(item => {
    if(!item.match(/RE:/)){
        Replace(arr, item, `RE: ${item}`);
    }
  });
}

/* code */
let users = [
"RE: Farman Ali",
"Usman",
"Fraz"
];

console.log(users);

EmailREAdder(users);

console.log(users);
```

Comment: This is a general answer. Functions can be applied to your specific input as you want.

Comment: In @SonEtLumiere's answer, we need to know index numeric value in advance. But in my solution, you just give the value, solution is expressive. Just input value. No need to enter index.